# Ubuntu 12.04 root open file limits

Tags: ubuntu

I have an issue with ulimits on ubuntu server 12.04 .

I've set a custom ulimit for open files .

`root soft nofile 20000`

`root hard nofile 60000`

This setting doesn't work , i've tried setting >pam_limits.so in /etc/pam.d/common-session

But still , nothing .

I want to mention that setting a limit for an user , on root it has the same value  .

If you set all (*) the root limits works .

I want to set the limits only for the root account .

Anyone had this issue ?
Does pam.d have any effect on this ?

Thanks ,
Alin